# Xamarin iOS Objective-C library binding - Build errors when creating a fat binary using "make" command

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a Xamarin iOS binding for this Objective C library [SPSlideTabController](http://github.com/aokizen/SPSlideTabBarController).

I have created a static library and am now in the process of creating a fat binary. I have the Makefile set up correctly and saved in the same folder as my static library. Not inside the static library folder though. Then I run the **make** command in the terminal.

Each time I have tried, only one file is generated **libSPSlideTabController-i386.a** then I get 4 build errors:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Release-iphoneos/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SPAppearance.o SPSlideTabBarController/Appearance/SPAppearance.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Release-iphoneos/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SPSlideTabBarItem.o SPSlideTabBarController/SPSlideTabBar/SPSlideTabBarItem.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Release-iphoneos/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SPSlideTabBar.o SPSlideTabBarController/SPSlideTabBar/SPSlideTabBar.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC build/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Release-iphoneos/SPSlideTabBarController.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SPSlideTabBarController.o SPSlideTabBarController/SPSlideTabBarController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
make: *** [libSPSlideTabBarController-armv7.a] Error 65
```

The **---armv7.a** and the **---SDK.a** files are not generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my Makefile

```
XBUILD=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
PROJECT_ROOT=./SPSlideTabBarController
PROJECT=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/SPSlideTabBarController.xcodeproj
TARGET=SPSlideTabBarController

all: lib$(TARGET).a

lib$(TARGET)-i386.a:
$(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphonesimulator 
-configuration Release clean build
-mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphonesimulator/lib$(TARGET).a $@

lib$(TARGET)-armv7.a:
$(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch 
armv7 -configuration Release clean build
-mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@

lib$(TARGET)-arm64.a:
$(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch 
arm64 -configuration Release clean build
-mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@

lib$(TARGET).a: lib$(TARGET)-i386.a lib$(TARGET)-armv7.a 
lib$(TARGET)-
arm64.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create -output $@ $^

clean:
-rm -f *.a *.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better that you share your MAKE file.

I normally open the code in XCode then add a runscript using my GIST [here](https://gist.github.com/tuyen-vuduc/eb8f53915727c73552884b35a705e9d3)

You could follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c) for more details.

Comment: I just added my Makefile.

Comment: The `makefile` runs well on my machine. Have you checked to you all steps listed in Xamarin guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/#Creating_A_Static_Library)? Otherwise, just open XCode, then follow the guide I shared above;it's always worth because you have to know that in most cases.